# How can I return specific values from a Parsed XML string

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, salesforce, apex

I'm trying to Parse an XML gateway response from our online payment gateway processor in a flow. Then take these variables to update various contact, opportunity and transaction records.
I'm struggling with getting the values from the XML

I just don't know much on XML Parseing so I'm trying to get the values I need returned first, then I can worry about retrying them from an @invocablemethod.

```
String trans = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><DirectPaymentResponse xmlns="https://api.ewaypaymentscom/"><DirectPaymentResult><AuthorisationCode>0000C</AuthorisationCode><ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>A2000</ResponseMessage><TransactionID>0000003</TransactionID><TransactionStatus>true</TransactionStatus><TransactionType>MOTO</TransactionType><BeagleScore>0.6</BeagleScore><Verification><CVN>Unchecked</CVN><Address>Unchecked</Address><Email>Unchecked</Email><Mobile>Unchecked</Mobile><Phone>Unchecked</Phone></Verification><Customer><TokenCustomerID>66666666</TokenCustomerID><Reference>Reference</Reference><Title>Mr.</Title><FirstName>aan</FirstName><LastName>McDat</LastName><CompanyName>Perkins</CompanyName><JobDescription>Officer</JobDescription><Street1>23 Verdun Street</Street1><Street2 /><City>Nedlands</City><State>WA</State><PostalCode>6009</PostalCode><Country>au</Country><Email>t@perkins.org.au</Email><Phone>0811111111</Phone><Mobile>0422222222</Mobile><Comments>Hi there</Comments><Fax /><Url>perkins.org.au</Url><CardDetails><Number>452012XXXXX9</Number><Name>ASd estt</Name><ExpiryMonth>1</ExpiryMonth><ExpiryYear>19</ExpiryYear><StartMonth /><StartYear /><IssueNumber /><CVN /></CardDetails></Customer><Payment><TotalAmount>200</TotalAmount><InvoiceNumber>0067F00000UmnAJ</InvoiceNumber><InvoiceDescription /><InvoiceReference /><CurrencyCode>AUD</CurrencyCode></Payment></DirectPaymentResult></DirectPaymentResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
```

Above is the String I receive

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
Doc.load(trans);
```

I then work down the nodes to try and get to the values.

```
Dom.XmlNode Env = doc.getRootElement();
system.debug('Root Element'+doc.getRootElement());

Dom.XmlNode body = Env.getChildElement('Body', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
system.debug('Child Element'+Env.getChildElement('Body', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'));

List<Dom.XmlNode> cElements = Env.getChildElements();
system.debug('Child Elements'+Env.getChildElements());

Dom.XmlNode DirectPR = body.getChildElement('DirectPaymentResponse','https://api.ewaypaymentscom/');


system.debug('DirectPR'+body.getChildElement('DirectPaymentResponse','https://api.ewaypaymentscom/'));

Dom.XmlNode DirectPResult = DirectPR.getChildElement('DirectPaymentResult','https://api.ewaypaymentscom/');
system.debug('Direct Payment Results'+DirectPR.getChildElement('DirectPaymentResult','https://api.ewaypaymentscom/'));

Dom.XmlNode AuthCodes = DirectPResult.getChildElement('AuthorisationCode', 'https://api.ewaypaymentscom/');
system.debug('Auth Element '+DirectPResult.getChildElement('AuthorisationCode', 'https://api.ewaypaymentscom/'));

Dom.XmlNode AUText = AuthCodes.getChildElement('Text', 'https://api.ewaypaymentscom/');
system.debug('Auth Element '+AuthCodes.getChildElement('Text', 'https://api.ewaypaymentscom/'));

String Conde = AuthCodes.getAttributeValue('AuthorisationCode', 'https://api.ewaypaymentscom/');
system.debug('Auth Code; '+AuthCodes.getAttributeValue('AuthorisationCode', 'https://api.ewaypaymentscom/'));`
```

I have tried to return the values but keep getting 'Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object'
And at one point also got 
'System.XmlException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not {'
But can't replicate that issue.
Note that I've removed the dots from the 'api.ewaypaymentscom' as it only lets me include 10. If I removed them from the getChildElement method it only returns null.
Currently I'm using the execute anon window to test the code but want to use it in an invocable method class.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I've figured it out,
I can pull the Values by

```
string AuthcodeTXT = AuthCodes.getText();
system.debug('Auth Code Text: '+ AuthCodes.getText());
```

And it returns '0000C'